# Braintree DropIn form displays change Payment Method

Tags: meteor, nodes, braintree

I am using Braintree DropIn Payment Form in Meteor Application. It works fine creates the form and is able to create a transaction. However when I submit the form it displays new screen that shows the current payment method and a link to update it. Once the sever returns the call my custom confirmation page is shown.

So the workflow sequence is:
1. DropIn Payment From (Credit card, exp dt, cvv, .. )
2. On click Submit button
3. onPaymentMethodReceived: part of the Setup is called
while it has not completed
4. A new temporary screen is displayed (option to change pymt method)
5. onPaymentMethodReceived : part completes and the custom Payment confirmation screen replaces the previous screen

How can I get rid of this update payment method screen.

Here is the code:

```
`Template.billPay.onRendered(function() {
  console.log('Satrt billPay Render');
  Meteor.call('getClientToken', function(error, clientToken) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Client Token Err');
      console.log(error);
    } else {
     braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
        container: "payment-form",
        onPaymentMethodReceived: function (response) {
          var nonce = response.nonce;
          Session.set('pymtResponse',response.details);
          Session.set('nonce',nonce);

          $('.paySubmit').prop('disabled', true);
           Meteor.call('btCreateCustomer', function(error, success) {
            if (error) {
              throw new Meteor.Error('customer-creation-failed');
            } else {
              Meteor.call('createTransaction', Session.get('nonce'), function(error, success) {
                 Session.set('pymtTxId', success.transaction.id);
                 Session.set('pymtTxId', success.transaction.id);
                }
              });
            }
          });
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });
});`
```

Comment: Will you add the server side code in which the client token is generated?

Comment: Here is the sever code that generates token:<br/>
`Meteor.methods({
  getClientToken: function (clientId) {
    var generateToken = Meteor.wrapAsync(gateway.clientToken.generate, gateway.clientToken);
    var options = {};
    var btId =  Meteor.user().custBtId;
    console.log('genToken btId '+btId);
     // options.customerId = btId;

   try {
    var response = generateToken(options);
   // console.log('client token'+response.clientToken);
    return response.clientToken;
   } catch (err) { console.log(err.message); return err}
  } })`

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact).</sub>

When a customer inputs a payment method, the selected payment method will display within the DOM element for your Drop-In UI in a compacted view, providing some basic information like the last 2 digits of the credit card number and the card brand, or a PayPal email address if that is selected. The "Change Payment Method" link and compact view is part of the Drop-In UI, and will display along with the customer's previous payment methods until the form is submitted.

That said, as you're using the [`onPaymentMethodReceived`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration) callback, the Drop-In UI will no longer inject a `payment_method_nonce` DOM element into your form and submit it, so in order to remove the Drop-in UI from your page, you can either hide the DOM element its displaying in by changing its `display` style value to `none`, or opt to use [`teardown`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/best-practices#teardown) which will remove anything created in the setup call, which includes the payment method display.